# How to Rescale List Range to Fit One Another?

Tags: python, math

I have two lists of unequal lengths:

```
Base_List (len=48): [19186.92, 19097.64, 18985.19, 18824.49, 18701.78, 18902.03, 18920.22, 19000.05, 19142.15, 19172.87, 19308.05, 19295.8, 19329.09, 19227.11, 19301.28, 19147.09, 19000.23, 19067.13, 19055.82, 18985.1, 18910.0, 18881.33, 18766.89, 18732.43, 18868.88, 18798.78, 18399.47, 17946.45, 17787.7, 17924.69, 17974.01, 17614.61, 16848.13, 17035.73, 17296.65, 17115.6, 17382.8, 17068.04, 16753.69, 16907.18, 16654.3, 16726.31, 16538.79, 16522.86, 17156.01, 17060.82, 17192.45, 17160.09]

Input_List(len=72): [272.97, 271.1, 271.0, 268.48, 267.67, 267.99, 268.2, 266.39, 266.98, 267.43, 270.34, 270.38, 271.6, 271.18, 270.0, 269.98, 269.41, 268.0, 266.64, 268.52, 267.65, 268.39, 271.95, 270.71, 271.49, 270.5, 270.97, 271.76, 269.99, 270.83, 269.31, 267.42, 261.13, 255.57, 254.02, 244.89, 248.41, 247.53, 249.15, 245.69, 245.71, 242.43, 229.79, 219.94, 226.82, 234.07, 230.01, 232.0, 227.18, 229.8, 232.55, 237.71, 235.0, 234.66, 221.79, 227.0, 219.75, 219.76, 221.59, 219.55, 217.74, 213.42, 207.29, 185.05, 193.0, 206.95, 197.02, 190.65, 194.0, 198.06, 194.9, 194.68]
```

How would I rescale the Input_List [:48] to the Base_List and then rescale Input_List [48:] by a proportional ratio without being limited by the range of the Base_List?

I have tried the below so far, but obviously the minimum of the rescaled Input_List cannot be less than the minimum of the Base_List:

```
def rescale(input_list, base_list):
    base_max = max(base_list)
    base_min = min(base_list)
    
    in_max = max(input_list)
    in_min = min(input_list)
    
    base_range = base_max - base_min
    in_range = in_max - in_min
    
    return [((((x-in_min)*base_range)/in_range)+base_min) for x in input_list]
```

Which would yield plotted out:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1T0p.png)

Thanks

Comment: Would it be better to scale both to be centered at zero first or is it important to keep the range of the base_list?

Comment: @DamonSnyder Thanks for replying. It's not important to keep the range of the base_list.

Comment: In many cases what you want to do is scale the data around 0 then plot or otherwise manipulate. Take a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html. The scale method may help with that part of your question. If you want to "extend" Input_list, you may have to perform some kind of extrapolation to "fill" in the missing entries to match the other list.